# Postgresql: insert the same data a few times

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have table `a`, in this table after a SQL request, I have the same records a few times.

Here is my request.

```
for server_id in (select bs.id from status.servers bs
  join settings.config blc on bs.id = blc.server_id
  where blc.lane_number = (dataitem->>'No')::SMALLINT AND blc.min_length <= (dataitem->>'len')::real
)
LOOP 
  insert into a(measurement_id, server_id, status)
  VALUES (
    measurement_id,server_id,false
  );
END LOOP;
```

And as result i have in table a, records like:

```
id  meas_id   serv_id   status
1   12        1         f
2   12        1         f
3   12        1         f
```

i've changed code a little, in working code there are not syntax mistakes

Comment: What is your question? Are you aware that you don't need a loop for that? You can do that with a **single** statement?

Comment: question is "why i have the same records with dif id?"

Comment: Why i dont? Look, i have 4 servers in status_servers. So for every server i need make insertion. So i need loop, no?

Comment: Sorry, i was editing when you are. And after i had saved ur edits were rewrited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering

> "why i have the same records with dif id?"

table a probably have a default value for column `id`, so values are taken from sequence. most probably you created it with `serial` data type... Those results are expected then. If you want to define your value, you should not skip column in scalar list, so

```
insert into a(measurement_id, server_id, status)
```

must become

```
insert into a(id, measurement_id, server_id, status)
```

and the value passed accordingly...

If you expected one result (assuming it from same value of server_id), you need to add `distinct` to the

```
for server_id in (select distinct bs.id from status.servers bs
```

because currently your select returns three rows with same `bs.id` as result of a `join` with three matching rows on join key...